# How do I fix this chunk lighting glitch?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a light glitch in the middle of a shop in my survival/adventure map.

Here it is. The large square of blue-looking wool in the center should be white:

[image]

The glitch is only visible at night, and the only way I know to fix it is to update the chunk with a light source. The problem is that the player will be in adventure mode inside the shop, so they won't be able to relight the chunk.

I've also tried to relight the chunk using MCEdit, but unfortunately that didn't work.

How do I work around this?

Comment: I am sorry, but I genuinely can't find a lightglitch. Could you clarify that or outline it in the picture?

Comment: @CrowleyAstray the wool in the square is supposed to be white.

Comment: How does the player enter that room?

Answer (score 2):

*"The only way I know to fix it is to update the chunk with a light source."*

simply use a **button** attached to a redstone lamp to update that chunk lightning.

I am sure that adventure players can press buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from placing blocks to eventually fix it you have two options:

- *NoLagg* plugin, which has an option to fix lights around yourself (but it hasn't seen updates for quite a while now).
- *mcedit* - select affected chunks -> chunk control -> relight

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but try placing a block in that chunk and taking it out. That usually works for me. If that doesn't work, unfortunately you might have to reset the chunk and rebuild that chunk again.

Answer (score -1):

try setting it to day, then back to night, it happens to me too, i'm using wii u edition though.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem that I fixed with WorldEdit by cutting and pasting the trouble areas. Just replacing the blocks didn't work.

Regards